# First all-grain batch, probably a disaster.

Tags: beginner, dms

I've been brewing with extract for 1 year with good results so I decided to move to all-grain brewing, with a Grainfather.
Last Sunday I brewed my first beer, an APA from an AG kit, but I made two mistakes when using my new toy:

1 - I accidentally removed the filter so my wort went in the fermenter with all its trub

2 - I failed while using my counterflow chiller and wort entered the fermenter at 40-45°C (105-115 Fahrenheit). Since I don't have a fridge, it took a lot of time to cool down to proper pitching temperature, around 12 hours.

Now the beer has been fermenting for 2-3 days at the right temperature with Mangrove Jack's M44 but it is producing a weird and quite disgusting olive/vegetable smell (maybe DMS?).

I tasted it and obviously that smell/flavor is there.

What do you think?
Is it too early to say anything?
Can it be DMS?

Should I throw out everything if it still tastes like this when primary is finished?

Comment: For mistake #1, what did you do to fix it?  Did you refilter it?

Comment: Nothing yet actually, even because I didn't think about it until after it happened. Since I'm dry hopping my plan is to filter just before bottling.

Comment: Trub is fine to go into the fermentor, just make sure you filter when bottling. I know brewers that do this everytime without any issues, the only thing you need to take into account is that you will have a bigger dead-space in your fermentation tank.

Answer (score 4):

No you are just fine. Relax, Denny Conn says "Barley wants to be turned into beer" and that is a great realization in this hobby, just make sure the yeast are fermenting...and enjoy the brew. Fermentation is often a smelly affair, but our yeast friends are great guests as they clean up after the party.

Answer (score 1):

Realy too Early. that smell its probably acetaldehide Just w8 10-14 days then cold for a few days then carbonate and then taste. 
your beer is Realy green for tasting right now. 
So please w8 for it. 
Dms generates between 64c and 100c so if you. Cold to 45 no dms issues.
try to add a second step for your counterflow, Just 2 metters of copper inside ice Will be enough for cold from 45c to 15-18c. 
Get a refrigerator fermentation temp is one of the most importants parts.
Bye hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok, usual homebrewing mistake then, I'll be patient! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DMS is created every moment the wort is hot converted from SMM(above 95°F if memory is correct)

Usually it's not an issue with 90 minute uncovered boils. This usually even allows for no chill overnight cooling with little DMS, but some grain bills will even so. DMS has a half life of 40 minutes at boil temp.

I would say it was from a short boil and slow chill made the DMS. And then converted DMSO which has a boil point much higher than water.

Unfortunately ones there it's there to stay yeast will not clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you shouldn't have anything to worry about.  In fact, I don't worry at all if hop particles get into my fermentor.  As far as cooling it goes, in an idea world, you'd want to get it to pitching temp and pitch yeast as soon as you can however, I've brewed with friends a few hours away and pitched when I got home with no adverse effect. I am curious about why you think you need to filter out the Vitamin B Complex (yeast) suspended in your beer.  These are important... if you drink too much, a bottle of water the next morning will cure your hangover but if you filter, those vitamins and minerals won't be there. Just cold crash it and be done.